# WPF - How to implement DataTemplate with complex logic?

Tags: wpf, treeview, datatemplate

I am currently transferring my app from **WinForms** to **WPF**.
Since I'm new in WPF, I stucked at creating DataTemplates for my treeView items. The screenshot shows how my treeview looked in **WinForms version**, and I need to get **close result in WPF**.

[(My WinForms treeview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PwHy.jpg)
As you can see, my DataTemplate's logic should take into account these factors:

1. Node type / defines which icon and fields combination will be displayed for particular item (node). App has about 7-8 node types. Type stored in separate node's field.
2. Variable values / I need to replace with text if null, etc
3. Numeric variable values / e.g.: set gray color if zero, etc.
4. Other properties / e.g.: adding textblocks depending on boolean fields.
5. And so on...

All these factors result into huge amount of **possible item params combinations**.

Also I'm using *DevComponents WPF DotNetBar AdvTree* to divide item properties into columns. I presume I should create 'sub templates' for different field sets and compose from them the entire DataTemplate for each column.
I've learned about **triggers**, and have to say that implementing my logic with triggers will make my subtemplates huge anyway.

[(Current state of my WPF treeview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpf6w.jpg)
So here are my questions:

1. Are there any ways to dynamically compose complex templates with C# code (**without** creating raw XAML and loading it at runtime)?
2. Maybe I should use completely different way (instead of using DataTemplate)? In Winforms I just used OwnerDraw mode, so the task was MUCH easier than in WPF :(
3. And how to display nested properties inside template? e.g.: *Item.Prop.Subprop1.Subprop2.**Targetprop***.

PS: English is not my first language, sorry for your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

1) The answer is yes. 
For exemple if you want to define a template in your window for a simple string

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(typeof(string));
    FrameworkElementFactory borderFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
    borderFactory.SetValue(Border.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(1));
    borderFactory.SetValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(1));
    borderFactory.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Red);

    FrameworkElementFactory textFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    textFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    });
    borderFactory.AppendChild(textFactory);
    template.VisualTree = borderFactory;

    myControl.ContentTemplate = template;
}
```

And in the Window you just put something like

```
<ContentControl x:Name="myControl" Content="Test text" Margin="10"/>
```

Your content control will render the string surrounded by a red border.
But as you anc see it is really complex to define your templates in this way.
The only scenario where i could imagine this approache is for some kind of procedurally generated templates.

Another way is to generate a string for the template and then load it with XamlReader:

```
string xaml = "<Ellipse Name=\"EllipseAdded\" Width=\"300.5\" Height=\"200\" 
Fill=\"Red\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>";
object ellipse = XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

2) I don't really see the need to generate templates in code behind. For exemple for this kind of data structure:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User Friend { get; set; }
}
public class RootNode
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
public class Node
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<SubNode> SubNodes { get; set; }
}
public class SubNode
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

You can define this type of template:

```
<Window 
        ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RootNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <StackPanel x:Name="spContainer" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding User.Friend.Friend.Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding User}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="spContainer" Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubNodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see you can define a template by data type, you can also use triggers to modify the behavior in specific cases, you could also use som binding converters...

3) You can bind to nested properties just like to normal ones :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding User.Friend.Friend.Name}"/>
```

However in some cases more than two level bindings could fail (fail to resolve or fail to update when property changes, ...)